# How to run all the test files and trigger test using maven-surefire plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am building a project in maven
I have some test files and I want them to be executed when I am compiling or packaging the project

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. The pom.xml looks like this

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.4</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>test</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>test</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <skip>false</skip>
                       <includes>
                           <include>src/test/java/**/com.example.AllTests.java</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <skip>false</skip>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. When I run the command "mvn clean install test", surefire runs but it skips all the test files.
3. When I run the command "mvn clean install -Dtest=com.example.AllTests.java -DfailIfNoTests=false" then the java file is run successfully

In a bigger and complex projects, I don't want to run multiple commands. I want to just run one command and I want maven to run the test files, generate the test reports and proceed further to run the application.

Can anyone please help me understand how I can achieve this with Maven.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: in point 1, you have `com.example.AllTests.java`  and in point 3 it's singular `com.example.AllTest.java`

Comment: oh please ignore... let me edit it

Answer (score 1):

Don't include `src/test/java/` but use `<include>com/example/AllTests.java</include>`.
Btw, in case of the surefire-plugin there's no need to specify execution block, since it's already called as part of the build-lifecycle (unless you have a rare setup). Configuration block is enough here.